# How to list instrument names in a Midi file with Java?

Tags: java, instruments, midi

I use the following code to play a midi file, but I couldn't find the list of instruments used :

```
      try
      {
        Sequence sequence=MidiSystem.getSequence(file);                                  // From file

        int trackNumber=0;
        for (Track track : sequence.getTracks())
        {
          trackNumber++;
          System.out.println("Track "+trackNumber+": size = "+track.size());
          System.out.println();
          for (int i=0;i<track.size();i++)
          {
            MidiEvent event=track.get(i);
            System.out.print("@"+event.getTick()+" ");
            if (message instanceof ShortMessage)
            {
              ShortMessage sm=(ShortMessage)message;
              System.out.print("Channel: "+sm.getChannel()+" "+new String(sm.getMessage())+" | ");
            }
            else Out("Other message: "+message.getClass());
          }
          System.out.println();
        }

        Sequencer sequencer=MidiSystem.getSequencer();
        sequencer.open();
        sequencer.setSequence(sequence);
        sequencer.start();                                                                               
      }
      catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
```

I did some search, there are similar questions, but none of them have straight answers, I just want a list instruments used in the file, such as Piano, drum ... I know the info is hidden in the messages [ maybe called "program" ?! ], but I just can't find it.

Comment: Try [`getCommand()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/midi/ShortMessage.html#getCommand()).

Comment: Have you checked the `Soundbank` object returned by `getSoundbank()`? It has a list of `Instrument` objects.

Comment: For cach channle, getCommand() will return 192,144,128,144,128 ...

Comment: I know Soundbank has a list of available instruments, but how do I know which instruments are use in my particular sound file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer, I finally figured it out :

```
Instrument instruments[];
Soundbank sb=synthesizer.getDefaultSoundbank();
if (sb!=null) instruments=synthesizer.getDefaultSoundbank().getInstruments();

...

      try
      {
        Sequence sequence=MidiSystem.getSequence(file);                                  // From file

        int trackNumber=0;
        for (Track track : sequence.getTracks())
        {
          System.out.print("Track "+(trackNumber++)+" : ");
          MidiEvent event=track.get(0);
          MidiMessage message=event.getMessage();
          if (message instanceof ShortMessage)
          {
            ShortMessage sm=(ShortMessage)message;
            if (sm.getCommand()==192) Out("sm.getChannel()="+sm.getChannel()+"  sm.getData1()="+sm.getData1()+"  "+instruments[sm.getData1()]);
          }
        }
```

The output looks like this :

```
Track 0 : sm.getChannel()=0  sm.getData1()=0  Instrument: Piano 1      bank #0 preset #0
Track 1 : sm.getChannel()=1  sm.getData1()=16  Instrument: Organ 1      bank #0 preset #16
Track 2 : sm.getChannel()=2  sm.getData1()=56  Instrument: Trumpet      bank #0 preset #56
Track 3 : sm.getChannel()=3  sm.getData1()=25  Instrument: Steel-str.Gt bank #0 preset #25
```